# Build dependent projects automatically if they are not build when bulding parent project in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I have three independent projects A, B and C. Projects B and C depend on project A jar. Every time there is a change in project A, i have to manually build it before building B and C.

I am trying to figure out, if there is a way to Build project A; every time i build project B or C independently. As these are independent projects, i don't think i have to use modules here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to rebuild B and C every time you introduce changes to A, I'd say, this is not a simple dependency between otherwise independent projects, and the coupling here is tighter than it seems.

You seem to know what maven modules are, and I would suggest to go that way.
Wrap all three of your projects with a ROOT maven project, and add them as modules to the root `pom.xml`.

Otherwise, think about *Continuous Integration Server*, like Jenkins or Hudson. In there, you can easily relate separate builds to trigger other builds, and also set them up, so they start automatically on every change comitted to version control system like SVN or GIT.

A scenario here would be quite simple:
`SVN change => triggers build of A => triggers build of B, C`

Comment: My project A has few common classes which are used in B and C. I think this work even work if - project A dependency is not found while building B or C and it automatically build A.